# min-width for table cells with wrapping text

Tags: html, css

I have a table where most cells contain only one word but it could be that a cell contains much longer text. I like in such a situation, this cell to have a min-width but all others not.

So it forces the table to be overflown on the `x-axis` and the text is more readable. I won't know in advance which of the cells could have how much text so can't put a `css` class on a particular one.

Is there a selector or something the says:

**If white-space wraps then it shall have a min-width?**

example markup here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxvy1Lwx/)

Answer (score 0):

No. you need to mark your HTML with a class. If you don't have access to modify the html you can select the column with css.

### with HTML

```
   <tr>
     <td> Normal</td>
     <td class="minwidth">Large</td>
   </tr>
   <style>
      .minwidth { min-width: 250px; }
   </style>
```

### Selecting with CSS the propper column

```
   table tr td:nth-child(2) { min-width: 250px; }
    /** this selects the second TD in all rows **/
```